# Automatically exit my application after 10 minutes of non interactions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

An example would be if a user sat their phone down with my application open and running but there had been no interactions with the application in the last ten minutes, the user should be logged out and have to sign in again. Is this a parameter that can be defined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the kind of behavior prohibited by Apple Developer Guidelines. Only the user should be able to quit an app. But I could be mistaken.

Comment: Well exiting is but are you meaning you could sign the user out of the app session and get the user to signin using username and password to keep using your app? If it is you could just use an NSTimer and stop and start it again each time you do something, fair bit of effort though

Comment: you just detact the touch on screen when a touch is tap then start Nstimer from start when timer reach ten minutes then quit the launch application or send user on login screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pre-defined parameter.  You have to check yourself using a timer method and/or by recording the time of the last user interaction.

It's perfectly legal for an app to display its login UIView (again) after 10 minutes, but don't try to exit the app instead.

Answer (score 1):

Quitting an active app, without user action/notification is considered bad form. However, if you must...

1. When your application starts, start
   a timer (NSTimer).
2. Instrument every method in your
   application to call a timer_reset
   function.
3. After 10 minutes call exit (0);

Have a look at the various NSTimer methods.

Comment: Calling `exit(0)` will likely cause Apple to reject your application if you submit it to the App Store.